# React component reset state with changing props and debounce

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, debouncing

sorry for the possible bad question or lack of info needed, this is my first question and I'm not a strong writer.

I have a component that isn't behaving correctly. What I want the component to do is be a set size, when a user hovers over the tile and after the timeout, download the movie in the background and the tile grows in size and auto plays the movie.

What is currently happening is the hover and debounce work well, but when its hovering it grows for a split second and then goes back to unhovered size. You can hover over it again and it works as intended.

What I think is going on is the component rerenders after the movie comes in with the movie clip downloaded, and the debounce hook is set back to false. So the component is no longer being hovered over, but once you hover over it again, since the movie is already downloaded and there is no changing props, it works as intended.

I have tried having the download call in the debounce hook, I have tried setting the movie as a ref, I tried having a separate hook to just hold the movie and the data is pulled from that 3rd hook. Some of those sound silly in retrospect.

As far as writing in react, I feel semi confident in writing in class components, not as confident in hooks, and uncomfortable in writing custom hooks. It is very possible something I have tried I didn't implement correctly. However it works flawlessly if I download all the movies the first time around, which is a bad idea. But it works well, which is cool!

This is the current state of the file, I'll clear out some garbage that isn't relevant, if someone has an idea of how I should move forward, I'm at a loss. I don't necessarily want code written for me, but maybe a nudge in a direction that would help.

```
import  React, { useState, useLayoutEffect, useEffect, useRef} from 'react';

const MovieTile = ( props ) => {


    const [hovering, setHovering] = useState(false);
    const debouncedMovie = useDebounced(props.hovering, 500, 50);


    useEffect(() => {
        if(!props.movie.movie_clip && debouncedMovie){
            props.fetchMovie(props.movie.id);
        }
        setHovering(debouncedMovie);
    }, [debouncedMovie])

    return(
        props.movie 
        ? <div 
            className='movie-tile' 
            id={debouncedMovie 
                ? 'hovered-movie-tile' 
                : null}
            onMouseEnter={() => {setHovering(true)}}
            onMouseLeave={() => {setHovering(false)}}
        >
            <video
                id={debouncedMovie ? 'hovered-movie-tile-video' : null} 
                className='movie-tile-video' 
                poster={props.movie.cover_art} 
                muted 
                loop
                autoPlay={debouncedMovie}>
                <source src={props.movie.movie_clip} type='video/webm'/>
                <source src={props.movie.movie_clip} type='video/mp4'/>
            </video>
            </div>
        </div>
        : null
    )
}

const useDebounced = (value, delayOn, delayOff) => {

    const [debouncedValue, setDebounceValue] = useState(value);

    useEffect( () => {
        let handler;
        if(value){
            handler = setTimeout(() => {
                setDebounceValue(value);
            }, delayOn);
        } else {
            handler = setTimeout(() => {
                setDebounceValue(value);
            }, delayOff)
        }
        return () => {
            clearTimeout(handler);
        }
    }, [value, delayOn, delayOff] );
    return debouncedValue;
}

export default MovieTile;
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Assuming props.fetchMovie sets props.movie.movie_clip, would it be feasible to not render unless props.movie.movie_clip is set?

Comment: I don't think so because it still needs to render the movie tile cover. It's just like Netflix tiles, where the cover is displayed first.

Comment: The only place that you are using `hovering` is where you pass it to `autoPlay`? If that's the case, you should be passing `props.hovering` to the initial state. And update `props.hovering` to `hovering` in order to use the local state.

Comment: Gosh that props.hovering isn't supposed to be there, it's supposed to be debounceMovie there. I was trying to add a hovering state to Redux, but realized right when I changed it to props.hovering that if it was set to true, every MovieTile, not just the hovering one would Autoplay. I'll update the code in the main prompt to reflect it now. Really sorry about that!